# How to check if an optional overloaded method is implemented?

Tags: swift

There are similar questions out there but I didn't find one that answered this specific one.

I was wondering.

There's an overloaded method with multiple signatures in a given protocol in swift.

```
optional func foo()
optional func foo(bar: Int)

optional func bar()
```

To check if the bar method was implemented I could go and just do:

```
if obj.bar != nil {
   obj.bar()
}
```

But how can I tell the method `foo(:Int)` instead of `foo` was implemented?
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optionally bind to a variable with an explicit
type annotation:

```
if let foo : (Void -> Void) = obj.foo {
    foo()
} else {
    print("`foo()` not implemented")
}

if let fooBar : (Int -> Void) = obj.foo {
    fooBar(1)
} else {
    print("`foo(bar: Int)` not implemented")
}
```